# Simplest way to upload data from desktop to a PHP website?

Tags: c#, php

This must be something very simple but I am not from a web background specially I don't know much about PHP.

I have C# based desktop application which is supposed to upload some data to a php based website in the background. Let's assume I have several text based fields like name, age, date, etc. I have to upload this information to a php based website which will be ultimately stored in a MySQL database.

What is the simplest way to achieve this? What should I do at server end? Host a web service that will be called be a C# application? should I use HTTP Post? Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP server end write a web service. If its a Restful Webservice it would be easy for you to access it. Your service must run on an URL. Your service must have exposed methods to do the CRUD operations or whichever operation in CRUD you want to use. For example

```
class MyService()
{
  public function insert_data()
  {
    if($_SERVER["request_code"] == "POST") {
      //handle json data here
    }
  }
```

So write a service like this and host in a public findable URL like

https://mydomain.com/api/insert_data

now send a POST request to it along with some json data from your client end which is trivial from any C# application.

When your service recieves it you must've writen code to parse the input validate it and store the data in a mysql DB.

You might also want to try and authenticate incoming request if its a secured data service.

For writing restful web service using php try out

http://recessframework.org

Answer (score 1):

I would do these things.

1. Send the required data through post method from c# desktop app.
2. Create a php script which receives the post variables.
3. this scripts will connect to the mysql and it will store the received data to mysql database.

php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['postvariable']))  {

    mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
    mysql_select_db("dbname");
    mysql_query(insert all the data here);

}
```

Comment: what about connect to mySQL database directly form c# app

Comment: @AminM are u taking about the desktop app? If so... you can still do that. But take care of the things properly and failing to take take of all the security things may make u end up in too many problems.